# Condition of continuity of characteristic function.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, characteristic-functions

Let $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ Then the characteristic function $\chi_E : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is continuous iff E is clopen.

Please provide me some hints or proof of above result.

Comment: If the characteristic function of $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is continuos, the preimage of $(1/2,3/2)$ should be open, and is equal to $E$. Anagolously, the preimage of $(-1/2,1/2)$ should be open and is the complement of $E$. So, $E$ is open and closed.

Comment: I don't know why these intervals are taken ?

Comment: You can choose any open set containing $1$ and not containing $0$ for the first part. And any open set containing $0$ and not containing $1$ for the second.

Comment: If your choice for $E$ is $(1/2,3/2)$ then complement of $E$ is $\mathbb{R}\setminus (1/2,3/2)$ but you told me that $E^c$ is the set $(-1/2,1/2)$ . this is my doubt.

Comment: No, $E$ is not that interval. A priori, we don't know what is $E$. Are you familiar with the topological characterization of continuity or do you prefer one with analysis?

Comment: Not the simplest answer, but perhaps good to know: the points at which $\chi_E$ is discontinuous are precisely the boundary points of $E$ and a set has empty boundary iff it's clopen.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{R}$ is connected so $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ is clopen iff $E=\emptyset$ or $E=\mathbb{R}$. Now $\chi_\emptyset:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is the constant function $=0$ and $\chi_\mathbb{R}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is the constant function $=1$. Both are continuous

If $\chi_E$ is continuous at $x\in\mathbb{R}$ then, because $\chi_E$ only takes values in $\{0,1\}$, there is some interval $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ where $\chi_E(t)=\chi_E(x)$ for all $t\in(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$. This means $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subseteq E$ if $x\in E$ so $E$ is open. By the same reasoning on $\mathbb{R}\setminus E$ and noting that 
$\chi_{\mathbb{R}\setminus E}=1-\chi_E$ is also continuous, $\mathbb{R}\setminus E$ is open and $E$ is closed $\implies E$ is clopen

Answer (score 0):

Let $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ then the characteristic function $\chi_E : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is defined by $\chi_E$ = $1$  if  $x \in E$ and $\chi_E$ = $0$  if $x  \in E^c $. If $\chi_E$ is continuous then inverse image of closed set must be closed. So $f^{-1}(\{0\}) = E$ is closed and $f^{-1}(\{1\}) = E^c$ is closed. This implies $E$ is open and closed both. If $E$ is both open and closed then $\chi_E$ is continuous. Am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

The function $\chi_E$ is open iff $\chi_E^{-1}(U)$ is open for every open $U$. We can write out what $\chi_E^{-1} (U)$ is in four cases.

1. If $0, 1 \not \in U$, then $\chi_E^{-1}(U) = \emptyset$.
2. If $0 \in U, 1 \not \in U$, then $\chi_E^{-1}(U) = E^\complement$.
3. if $0 \not \in U, 1 \in U$, then $\chi_E^{-1}(U) = E$.
4. If $0, 1 \in U$, then $\chi_E^{-1}(U) = \mathbb{R}$.

So while $\emptyset, \mathbb{R}$ are always open, we also need $E, E^\complement$ to be open. This’ll happen iff $E$ is clopen.